# How can I prove / disprove If A ↠ B then AC ↠ B

Tags: normalization, relational-theory, dependencies

If A ↠ B then AC ↠ B is it true or false and if so can have example why?

Comment: Double-headed arrow is a MVD. There are Armstrong axioms for both FDs & MVDs.

Answer (score 4):

I think it follows from the [composition property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency), which says that if A → B and C → D, then AC → BD. If D = ∅ then you arrive at the desired result.

This applies to [multivalued dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency) as well: If A ↠ B and D ⊆ C, then AC ↠ BD, which in the case of D = ∅ devolves into AC ↠ B.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio. Assuming the double-headed arrow means multivalued dependency (the o.p. gives so little context, I'm not sure they know what they're asking), your first para doesn't apply, because that's only for Functional Dependencies. For a MVD the implication does not hold in general. (It does hold trivially if `C ⊆ A`, but we can't assume that.) I think o.p. should show more effort before anybody says more.

Comment: @AntC The implication holds, it's just not presented clearly, the use of the linked rule & other phrasing including "case of D=" is unclear. The rule is "If X ↠ Y and Z ⊆ W, then XW ↠ YZ". We have A ↠ B and ∅ ⊆ C. Plugging A, B, ∅ & C for X, Y, Z & W, the rule gives "If A ↠ B and ∅ ⊆ C, then AC ↠ B∅". And since the if holds, the then holds. So AC ↠ B∅ ie AC ↠ B. The FD presentation fails to show C → ∅, which arises when taking its rule's W to be ∅. It happens that C → ∅; a justification is that that's a trivial FD. Armstrong gives it via reflexivity.